# Are (Z/21Z)* and (Z/13Z)* isomorphic? Find an isomorphism between these two group if they are.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are $(Z/21Z)^*$ and $(Z/13Z)^*$ isomorphic? Find an isomorphism between these two group if they are.

$(Z/21Z)^*$ and $(Z/13Z)^*$ are the multiplicative integer modulo group.

I have tried constructing the function but I just can't find one. Based on the order of the element, I know 2,11,4,1,8,16 must map to 4,10,3,1,12,9 but I can't find a bijection for the rest.

Comment: You should try finding a generator for each group. $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, so if they're isomorphic, then $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$ should be cyclic too.

Comment: so they are not isomorphic?

Answer (score 3):

The [structure of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure) is:
$$(\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z)^*\approx\Bbb Z/\phi(13)\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z,$$
$$(\Bbb Z/21\Bbb Z)^*\approx(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^*\times(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^*\approx
(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z).$$
They are isomorphic?

Comment: How can i tell?

Comment: after finding the order of all the elements, I realise that z/21 does not have element of order 12 so non of them generate the group so it means that it is not cyclic so it is no isomorphic to z13 but i am wondering how can i tell without painstakingly finding the order of all the elements. I am not quite sure how your example tell me directly. On top of that i thought there is a theorem that says two finite abelian group are isomorphic if they have the same number of elements. aren't these two group finite abelian?

Comment: @user136266, your "theorem" is false: $C_4\not\approx C_2\times C_2$. The order of the elements of $C_6\times C_2$ is obviously $\le 6$. Why?

Comment: else the element will not belong to $C_6 \times 1$ or $1 \times C_2$? how do you get the isomorphism in the first place? Is there any theorems on this. I have not encountered this before.

Comment: actually i don't quite know why it cannot be >6

Comment: @user136266, take $(a,b)\in C_6\times C_2$. What is $(a,b)+(a,b)+(a,b)+(a,b)+(a,b)+(a,b)$? An see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group.

Comment: $(a^6, (b^2)^3) = (1,1)$ so if $x \in C_6 \times C_2$, it can have at most order 6. Is there a generalisation of this fact? Is it true that the product of cyclic groups can have at most order of the lcm of the order of the group? I think it is true

Comment: @user136266, order of *elements* isn't the same that order of the *group*.

Comment: but it is true for cyclic group isn't it?

Comment: @user136266, order of identity?

Comment: ok then what should be the correct generalisation? the element of a product of cyclic groups can have at most order of the lcm of the order of each of the cyclic groups?

Comment: @user136266, right.